# I'm getting an Error using built-in Constraint Annotations using Maven

Tags: annotations, maven-3, java-ee-7

I'm using maven 3, junit 4.11, hibernate.validator 5.0.1.Final and jdk 1.7. When using a standard built-in constraint annotation, I get the following error, which doesn't appear using a self-written constraint class.

I have no clue why this is happening.

Thanks
Heinz

Error Log:

```
shouldRaiseConstraintViolationCauseInvalidEmail(org.agoncal.book.javaee7.chapter03.CustomerIT)      Time elapsed: 0.011 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: null
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at javax.el.FactoryFinder.newInstance(FactoryFinder.java:87)
    at javax.el.FactoryFinder.find(FactoryFinder.java:197)
    at javax.el.ExpressionFactory.newInstance(ExpressionFactory.java:197)
    at javax.el.ExpressionFactory.newInstance(ExpressionFactory.java:168)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.messageinterpolation.InterpolationTerm.<clinit>(InterpolationTerm.java:60)
    at org.hibernate.validator.messageinterpolation.ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator.interpolateExpression(ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator.java:227)
    at org.hibernate.validator.messageinterpolation.ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator.interpolateMessage(ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator.java:187)
    at org.hibernate.validator.messageinterpolation.ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator.interpolate(ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator.java:115)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidationContext.interpolate(ValidationContext.java:370)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidationContext.createConstraintViolation(ValidationContext.java:284)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidationContext.createConstraintViolations(ValidationContext.java:246)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintTree.validateSingleConstraint(ConstraintTree.java:289)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintTree.validateConstraints(ConstraintTree.java:133)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintTree.validateComposingConstraints(ConstraintTree.java:233)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintTree.validateConstraints(ConstraintTree.java:102)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintTree.validateConstraints(ConstraintTree.java:91)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.core.MetaConstraint.validateConstraint(MetaConstraint.java:85)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraint(ValidatorImpl.java:478)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraintsForDefaultGroup(ValidatorImpl.java:424)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraintsForCurrentGroup(ValidatorImpl.java:388)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateInContext(ValidatorImpl.java:340)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validate(ValidatorImpl.java:158)
    at org.agoncal.book.javaee7.chapter03.CustomerIT.shouldRaiseConstraintViolationCauseInvalidEmail(CustomerIT.java:47)
```

Email.java:

```
import javax.validation.Constraint;
import javax.validation.Payload;
import javax.validation.ReportAsSingleViolation;
import javax.validation.constraints.Pattern;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.*;
import static java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME;

@Size(min = 7)
@Pattern(regexp = "[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\\."
    + "[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*"
    + "@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?") 
@ReportAsSingleViolation
@Constraint(validatedBy = {})
@Target({METHOD, FIELD, ANNOTATION_TYPE, CONSTRUCTOR, PARAMETER})
@Retention(RUNTIME)
public @interface Email {

    String message() default "{org.agoncal.book.javaee7.chapter03.Email.message}";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};

    @Target({METHOD, FIELD, ANNOTATION_TYPE, CONSTRUCTOR, PARAMETER})
    @Retention(RUNTIME)
    @interface List {
        Email[] value();
    }
}
```

And the test class:

```
import org.junit.AfterClass;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.Test;

import javax.validation.ConstraintViolation;
import javax.validation.Validation;
import javax.validation.Validator;
import javax.validation.ValidatorFactory;
import java.util.Set;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

public class CustomerIT {

    private static ValidatorFactory vf;
    private static Validator validator;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void init() {
        vf = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
        validator = vf.getValidator();
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void close() {
        vf.close();
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldRaiseConstraintViolationCauseInvalidEmail() {

        Customer customer = new Customer("John", "Smith", "DummyEmail");
        Set<ConstraintViolation<Customer>> violations = validator.validate(customer); <----- Error
        assertEquals(1, violations.size());
        assertEquals("invalid email address", violations.iterator().next().getMessage());
        assertEquals("DummyEmail", violations.iterator().next().getInvalidValue());
        assertEquals("{org.agoncal.book.javaee7.chapter03.Email.message}", violations.iterator().next().getMessageTemplate());
    }
}
```

Customer Cass (without getters and setters):

```
public class Customer {

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 2)
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    @Email
    private String email;
    private String phoneNumber;
    @Past
    private Date dateOfBirth;
    private Address deliveryAddress;

    public Customer() {
    }

    public Customer(String firstName, String lastName, String email) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.email = email;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I was doing the exact same tutorial (from Beginning Java EE 7) and having the exact same issue. This answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/20773679 helped clarify the issue. 
What needed to be done was add the following dependencies to my/your pom:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>javax.el</groupId>
<artifactId>javax.el-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
<artifactId>el-impl</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Hope this answer isn't too late to help somebody.