# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/el/PropertyNotFoundException when I send invalid values to controller

Tags: java, hibernate, validation, testing, spring-mvc

I use MockMvc for my controller testing

```
@Test
    public void updateEvent() throws Exception{
        MockHttpServletRequestBuilder request = MockMvcRequestBuilders
                .post("/updateEvent");
        request.param("selectedEventStatusId", "1");
        request.param("selectedEventTypeId", "1");



        Event eventFromDb = createAndSaveEvent();
        request.param("idEvent", eventFromDb.getId().toString());
        request.param("name", eventFromDb.getName());
        request.param("description", eventFromDb.getDescription() +"____");//the reason of problem. if I will write request.param("description", eventFromDb.getDescription() );  its good work mapping if this field below
        request.param("date", new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(eventFromDb.getDate()));
        request.param("eventDate", new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(eventFromDb.getEventDate()));


        ResultActions result = mockMvc.perform(request).andDo(MockMvcResultHandlers.print());

        result.andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.view().name("redirect:eventDetails"));
        result.andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.model().attributeExists("idEvent"));
        result.andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.model().attributeExists("message"));

    }
```

description field mark as

```
    @Size(min=5)
    @Pattern(regexp="[a-zA-Z]*")    
    private String description;
```

I see next stackTrace after execution:

```
 org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/el/PropertyNotFoundException
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.triggerAfterCompletionWithError(DispatcherServlet.java:1259)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:945)
        at ....
```

In production mode it good work but in test I see error if I have notValid value

controller method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/updateEvent", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String updateEvent(Model model,
            @Valid @ModelAttribute("existedEvent") Event event,
            BindingResult result,
            @ModelAttribute("linkedCandidates") Set<Candidate> candidates,
            @ModelAttribute("linkedvacancies") Set<Vacancy> vacancies,
            @RequestParam(required = true, value = "selectedEventStatusId")Integer EventStatusId,
            @RequestParam(required = true, value = "selectedEventTypeId")Integer EventTypeId ,
            RedirectAttributes attributes) {
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            //model.addAttribute("idEvent", event.getId());
            event.setCandidates(candidates);
            event.setVacancies(vacancies);
            return "eventDetails";
        }
        eventService.updateEventAndLinkedEntities(event, candidates, vacancies,EventTypeId,EventStatusId);
        attributes.addAttribute("idEvent",event.getId() );
        attributes.addAttribute("message", "submitted correctly at "+new Date());
        return "redirect:eventDetails";
    }
```

If I replace

```
 request.param("description", eventFromDb.getDescription() +"____");
```

on

```
request.param("description", eventFromDb.getDescription();//valid value here
```

It is good works

Can you help to fix it?

**UPDATE**

pom.xml(child module - tests running here)

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.epam.hhs</groupId>
    <artifactId>ui</artifactId>
    <name>hhsystem ui</name>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <java-version>1.6</java-version>
        <org.springframework-version>3.2.3.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
        <org.springsecurity-version>3.1.3.RELEASE</org.springsecurity-version>
        <org.aspectj-version>1.6.10</org.aspectj-version>
        <org.slf4j-version>1.6.6</org.slf4j-version>
        <!-- Spring -->
        <spring-framework.version>3.2.3.RELEASE</spring-framework.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Security -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springsecurity-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springsecurity-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springsecurity-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springsecurity-version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Validation -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.epam.hhs</groupId>
            <artifactId>core</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.9-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.epam.hhs</groupId>
            <artifactId>core</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.9-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <classifier>tests</classifier>
        </dependency>

        <!-- AspectJ -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>${org.aspectj-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.15</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- @Inject -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Servlet -->
         <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope> 
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope> 
        </dependency> 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
            <artifactId>el-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope> 
        </dependency>


        <!-- Test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.7</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Mock MVC Test -->
        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>org.springframework</groupId> <artifactId>spring-test-mvc</artifactId> 
            <version>1.0.0.M2</version> <scope>test</scope> </dependency> -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>junit</groupId> <artifactId>junit</artifactId> 
            <version>4.10</version> <scope>test</scope> <exclusions> <exclusion> <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId> 
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId> </exclusion> </exclusions> </dependency> -->
        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>com.github.springtestdbunit</groupId> <artifactId>spring-test-dbunit</artifactId> 
            <version>1.0.0</version> <scope>test</scope> </dependency> <dependency> <groupId>org.dbunit</groupId> 
            <artifactId>dbunit</artifactId> <version>2.4.8</version> <scope>test</scope> 
            </dependency> -->

    </dependencies>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestone</id>
            <name>Spring Portfolio Milestone Repository</name>
            <url>http://repo.springsource.org/milestone/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9</version>
                <configuration>
                    <additionalProjectnatures>
                        <projectnature>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springnature</projectnature>
                    </additionalProjectnatures>
                    <additionalBuildcommands>
                        <buildcommand>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springbuilder</buildcommand>
                    </additionalBuildcommands>
                    <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                    <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                    <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
                    <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                    <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>org.test.int1.Main</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <!-- <plugin> <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId> <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId> 
                <version>2.12</version> <configuration> <forkMode>always</forkMode> </configuration> 
                </plugin> -->
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

pom.xml(parent module)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.epam.hhs</groupId>
    <artifactId>core</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.9-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <name>hhsystem core</name>
    <!--<packaging>war</packaging> -->

    <properties>

        <!-- Generic properties -->
        <java.version>1.6</java.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>

        <!-- Spring -->
        <spring-framework.version>3.2.3.RELEASE</spring-framework.version>
        <spring-data-jpa.version>1.3.2.RELEASE</spring-data-jpa.version>
        <org.springsecurity-version>3.1.3.RELEASE</org.springsecurity-version>

        <!-- Java EE / Java SE dependencies -->
        <jsp.version>2.2</jsp.version>
        <jstl.version>1.2</jstl.version>
        <servlet.version>2.5</servlet.version>
        <jaxb-impl.version>2.2.7</jaxb-impl.version>

        <!-- Hibernate / JPA -->
        <hibernate.version>4.2.1.Final</hibernate.version>

        <!-- Bean validation -->
        <hibernate-validator.version>4.3.1.Final</hibernate-validator.version>

        <!-- Database access -->
        <tomcat-jdbc.version>7.0.37</tomcat-jdbc.version>
        <ehcache.version>2.6.6</ehcache.version>
        <hsqldb.version>2.2.9</hsqldb.version>

        <!-- AOP -->
        <aspectj.version>1.7.2</aspectj.version>

        <!-- Logging -->
        <logback.version>1.0.13</logback.version>
        <slf4j.version>1.7.5</slf4j.version>

        <!-- RSS -->
        <rome.version>1.0</rome.version>

        <!-- Test -->
        <junit.version>4.11</junit.version>
        <hamcrest.version>1.3</hamcrest.version>

        <!-- Dates -->
        <jodatime-hibernate.version>1.3</jodatime-hibernate.version>
        <jodatime-jsptags.version>1.1.1</jodatime-jsptags.version>
        <jodatime.version>2.2</jodatime.version>
        <jadira-usertype-core.version>3.1.0.CR6</jadira-usertype-core.version>


        <!-- Web dependencies -->
        <webjars-bootstrap.version>2.3.0</webjars-bootstrap.version>
        <webjars-jquery-ui.version>1.9.2</webjars-jquery-ui.version>
        <webjars-jquery.version>1.9.0</webjars-jquery.version>
        <dandelion.datatables.version>0.8.14</dandelion.datatables.version>

        <mysql.version>5.1.22</mysql.version>

    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.transports</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-transport-http</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.0</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>${jstl.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>${servlet.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>${jsp.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency> -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
            <version>${jaxb-impl.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- SPRING, SPRING, SPRINGITY SPRING -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-data-jpa.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- used for EhCacheCacheManager -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Database connection pool See here for more details on commons-dbcp 
            versus tomcat-jdbc: http://blog.ippon.fr/2013/03/13/improving-the-performance-of-the-spring-petclinic-sample-application-part-3-of-5/ -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${tomcat-jdbc.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- For MySql only -->
        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>mysql</groupId> <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId> 
            <version>${mysql.version}</version> </dependency> -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>sqljdbc4</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>mysql</groupId> <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId> 
            <version>${mysql.version}</version> </dependency> -->
        <!-- HIBERNATE -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate-validator.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.25</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Webjars (static dependencies distributed as JAR files) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
            <version>${webjars-bootstrap.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>jquery-ui</artifactId>
            <version>${webjars-jquery-ui.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
            <version>${webjars-jquery.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Test Artifacts -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- used by Spring MVC Test framework -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-library</artifactId>
            <version>${hamcrest.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
            <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Security -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springsecurity-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springsecurity-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springsecurity-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.ow2.easybeans</groupId>
            <artifactId>easybeans-uberjar-eclipselink</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.0-M1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <!-- Maven plugin versions are mentioned in order to guarantee the build 
        reproducibility in the long term -->
    <build>
        <defaultGoal>install</defaultGoal>
        <testResources>
            <testResource>
                <!-- declared explicitly so Spring config files can be placed next to 
                    their corresponding JUnit test class (see example with ValidatorTests) -->
                <directory>${project.basedir}/src/test/java</directory>
            </testResource>
            <testResource>
                <directory>${project.basedir}/src/test/resources</directory>
            </testResource>
        </testResources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <compilerArguments>
                        <Xlint />
                    </compilerArguments>
                    <verbose>true</verbose>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                    <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9</version>
                <configuration>
                    <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                    <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
                    <wtpversion>2.0</wtpversion>
                    <sourceIncludes>
                        <sourceInclude>**/*.*</sourceInclude>
                    </sourceIncludes>
                    <additionalBuildcommands>
                        <buildCommand>
                            <name>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springbuilder</name>
                        </buildCommand>
                        <buildCommand>
                            <name>org.eclipse.m2e.core.maven2Builder</name>
                        </buildCommand>
                    </additionalBuildcommands>
                    <additionalProjectnatures>
                        <projectnature>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature</projectnature>
                        <projectnature>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springnature</projectnature>
                        <projectnature>org.eclipse.m2e.core.maven2Nature</projectnature>
                    </additionalProjectnatures>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <server>tomcat-development-server</server>
                    <port>9966</port>
                    <path>/petclinic</path>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test-jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I restart my pc and now I see other error(maybe i change something But I posted actual dtate of pom.xml)

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.el.ExpressionFactory.newInstance()Ljavax/el/ExpressionFactory;
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.triggerAfterCompletionWithError(DispatcherServlet.java:1259)
    at ...
```

If I change jsp-api version on `2.2`

I see next trace:

```
    updateEvent(com.epam.hhsystem.web.controllers.EventMenuControllerTest)  Time elapsed: 0.398 sec  <<< ERROR!
    org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.triggerAfterCompletionWithError(DispatcherServlet.java:1259)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:945)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
....
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.hibernate.validator.messageinterpolation.ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator.interpolateExpression(ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator.java:227)

    ....
Caused by: javax.el.ELException: Provider com.sun.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl not found
    at javax.el.FactoryFinder.newInstance(FactoryFinder.java:97)

...
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I haven't `el-impl`  in my pom.xml

```
 <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
                <version>2.5</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
                <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
                <version>1.2</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
                <artifactId>el-api</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
                <artifactId>el-impl</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
            </dependency>
```

It is working state of pom.xml

An more I delete

```
servlet-api
jsp-api
jstl
el-api
```

jar files from `tomcat/lib`

And copy from `m2./repository`.

Answer (score 40):

I met the same problem, Add the following dependency resolved this problem.

When you met javax/el/PropertyNotFoundException， That means you missed el-api dependency, you can add the following jar

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
        <artifactId>el-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

or

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
  <artifactId>javax.el-api</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.0</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Then you met ClassNotFoundException:com.sun.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl , You missed el-impl jar:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
  <artifactId>el-impl</artifactId>
  <version>2.2</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I have the same issue as the person who has posted the Problem, and this answer works for me! Place accepted this as the right one. same on the answer from @AlperAkture

Comment: If you add `el-impl`, then you can remove `el-api` dependency from pom. It will be included by `el-impl` as a transitive dependency.

Comment: If you add `el-impl` with test scope, then it is not automatically available during the normal `compile` phase.

Answer (score 7):

Add the following to your pom.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
  <artifactId>el-impl</artifactId>
  <version>2.2.6</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

It will resolve the need for javax.el. Current version is 2.2.6

Comment: Is the version 2.2.6 is really available in maven repo? I didn't find it [here](https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/glassfish/web/el-impl/). My issue fixed with 2.2 version though.

Comment: For some background why this needs to be added, see the [Hibernate Validator Get Started Guide](http://hibernate.org/validator/documentation/getting-started/#unified-expression-language-el). It also shows which version should be used with the latest hibernate version.

Answer (score 2):

You maybe just need to add the dependency in your test. Are you using maven? if so, can you try to add this to your pom? You may need a different jar/version, but something like this:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
  <artifactId>javax.el-api</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.0</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: You are right. I use maven. My project consist on 2 modules. This test in child module. I have similar dependency. with **    <dependency>
 <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
 <artifactId>el-api</artifactId>   <scope>provided</scope>
 <version>2.2</version>
</dependency>
            **

Comment: You are sure that the versions are same in the test and in prod? How are you running the test, from command line, or with an IDE?

Comment: Oh, you have <scope>provided</scope>, can you try to remove that or make it <scope>test</scope> ? I'm not sure if provided scope dependencies get included for running tests. Also, you may want to verify that the missing class is in the jar, you can do something like "jar -tvf el-api-3.0.0.jar | grep PropertyNotFoundException"

Comment: It seems <scope>provided</scope> will be included in tests, so that would not be the problem. I also see the PropertyNotFoundException.class is in the 2.2 jar. So the issue must be in the pom setup. do you want to post those here?

Comment: I see jsp-api-2.1 has an abstract javax.el.ExpressionFactorybut no newInstance() method, as you found. jsp-api-2.2 removed ExpressionFactory, so it picks it up from el-api-2.2, but there's no implementation (that I can see in your pom). I did find an ExpressionFactoryImpl in this dependency:  <dependency>
   <groupId>com.sun.el</groupId>
   <artifactId>el-ri</artifactId>
   <version>1.0</version>
  </dependency>  , which may fix your latest ClassNotFoundException, can you try it, possibly will cause another error. I will also look at a few more things to try.